# How can repair characters to original state after switching from Polish to Japanese back to Polish again?

Tags: windows, language

I’ve got a small problem with trash code that seems to be stuck in my PC after switching system language. Mainly on command prompt, but also as I can see on codes, I’ve shared from another PC. However, this is only on display, but after I will write in my language it just works normally. `śćźżóąęń` works.

- My system language is Polish.
- System was switched to Japanese language for a short period of time.

I have uninstalled keyboard and system lang, before I upgraded system to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1.

[image: heres the example]

Comment: Your command prompt code page is most likely set to [932](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx). You can check this in your command prompt with `chcp`. And you can change it back to whatever you want with ie `chcp 65001`. Close and reopen your CMD window after it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **change the system locale for non-Unicode programs**.

1. Go to **Control Panel** (click on the Start button or press the <kbd>Win Key</kbd> on your keyboard, then type "Control Panel" without the quotes).
   [image: Control Panel]
2. Click on **Clock, Language and Region**.
   [image: Clock, Language and Region]
3. Click on **Region**.
   [image: Region]
4. Click on the **Administrative** tab.
   [image: Administrative Tab]
5. Click on the **Change system locale** button (mine says "Hebrew (Israel)" in the current language for non-Unicode programs, but yours should show "Japanese (Japan)").
   [image: Change System Locale Button]
6. Change the set value to the language of your choice - I'm assuming it's "Polish (Poland)".
   [image: Polish (Poland) Language]
7. Click the **OK** button. You will be prompted to restart your system; the changes will take place when you do (you don't have to do so right away though).